# Silverlight 5 Application cannot get HasElevatedPermissions to be true

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I am using Silverlight 5 RC on a Windows 7 x64 OS running IE9.
I am trying to get HasElevatedPermissions=True.
I have made the necessary change to the Windows registry and signed the xap using a test certificate as documented here :

http://pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Silverlight-5-Tidbits-Trusted-applications.aspx

I even chose the  Use Local IIS Web Server option on the Web project and a project Url with a localhost domain.

I still get HasElevatedPermissions=False.

When I checked the two boxes to Require Elevated trust both outside and in the browser, I got this message:
{System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(System.__Canon)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.
   at System.Windows.Controls.DomainDataSource.InitializeView()
   at System.Windows.Controls.DomainDataSource..ctor()}

Someone kindly tell me what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the registry keys or include "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" in your certificate as explained below:

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/10-Laps-around-Silverlight-5-Part-10-of-10.aspx